# How to import csv into List<object> in C#

Tags: c#, list, csv, initialization, initializer-list

I am creating a List object with the folowing class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public int E { get; set; }
}
```

Like so:

```
public List<Item> Flower = new List<Item>{};
```

How would I go about initializing this list with the contents of a csv file that is structured like so?

```
A,B,C,D,1
```

Comment: you'd write code that read the CSV, looping over each line and initializing you object and adding it to the collection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing CSV file into a List using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152453/importing-csv-file-into-a-list-using-c-sharp)

Comment: You could start by reading each line of the file, calling [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) to separate it into separate fields, and then copy those to your class. Or you could use [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx), which is what I'd recommend.

Comment: ( csvhelper lib ) https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like...

```
var listOfObjects = File.ReadLines( "theFile.csv" ).Select( line => new Item( line ) ).ToList();
```

and

```
 class Item
 {
     public Item( string line )
     {
         var split = line.Split(',');
         A = split[0];
         B = split[1];
         C = split[2];
         D = split[3];
         E = int.Parse( split[4] );
     }

     // [...]
 }
```

and add some error handling, of course...

Comment: Nice, but use File.ReadLines

Comment: Also considering the data `A,B,C,D,1` think the delimiter should be a comma, `var split = line.Split(',');`